# Does pair.first return a reference to the first value?

Tags: c++, reference, standard-library, std-pair

In the C++ standard library, there is an object called the pair. Pair.first and Pair.second return the first and second values of the pair object, respectively. I want to increment the first value by one under a conditional (my pair is a pair). It's throwing "needs 1-value" when I try to do this. This could be because somewhere along the way I am not passing in a value by reference, but it could also be that .first does not return the first value of the pair by reference.
Does anyone know if it does?

Comment: Please show *minimal* code exhibiting your problem. The way you describe it, it should work (but it doesn't, so there's something fishy).

Answer (score 9):

`first` is not a function, it is an object itself, a data member of `struct pair`. The name of an object is an lvalue, equivalent to a reference.

"Lvalue" is a language term denoting something that can go on the left-hand side of an assignment, i.e. a value can be assigned to it, or it has a meaningful address in memory.

The result of a conditional expression is an lvalue if both its alternatives are lvalues of the same type.

For example,

```
pair< int, int > p;
flag? p.first : p.second = 34; // ok

flag? p.first : 3 = 15; // error: 3 is not an lvalue; 3 = 15 is nonsense

pair< int, short > q;
flag? q.first : q.second = 12; // error: different types
```

Note, the opposite of "lvalue" is "rvalue," for right-hand side of an assignment. These terms are borrowed from the C language.

Remember: the lvalue of an expression is where it is stored, the rvalue is its content. Which of these an expression meaningfully has decide its *value category*.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I think that what you are reading as "needs 1-value" is actually "needs **lvalue**" (L-value), which in C++ is an expression that (intuitively) represents an actual object rather than something that is a value.

Next, `pair.first` and `pair.second` don't yield references to `pair.first` and `pair.second`, but rather *are* the `first` and `second` data members inside of `pair`.  You can obtain references to them, but they themselves are not references.

Without seeing the actual code, though, I can't offer any more targeted advice.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Pairs are the standard way to implement 1-value to 2-value conversion, though :-)